# missing Anaconda navigator after installing the last version of anaconda on windows 10

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I've just installed the latest version of Anaconda "Anaconda 5.0.1 For Windows Installer" on windows but can't find the Anaconda Navigator on the search menu. Plus when i tried to run the command conda It's not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

### [when i seach on anaconda navigator in the windows menu I get this file as a result and not the icon of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAZJZ.png)

### [this is the error I got when i try the conda command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKQ9U.png)

[I already got anaconda in my path variable here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fr1k.png)